# Pandas: fill non empty value with name of the column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill the non empty value of my datatable with corresponding column name. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['2000-01-01 00:00:10.870', '2000-01-03 00:00:08.160','2000-01-03 00:00:10.870', '2000-01-06 00:00:11.160'],
                   'E1 ':[1 ,np.nan, 1, 1],'E2 ':[1 ,np.nan, 1, 1]})
```

### output:

```
E1  E2  Time
0   1.0 1.0 2000-01-01 00:00:10.870
1           2000-01-03 00:00:08.160
2   1.0 1.0 2000-01-03 00:00:10.870
3   1.0 1.0 2000-01-06 00:00:11.160
```

Desired out put:

```
     E1 E2  Time
0   E1  E2  2000-01-01 00:00:10.870
1           2000-01-03 00:00:08.160
2   E1  E2  2000-01-03 00:00:10.870
3   E1  E2  2000-01-06 00:00:11.160
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
for col in ['E1 ', 'E2 ']:
    df.loc[df[col].notnull(), col] = col
```

If you have more columns that you want to include, you could just make a list of those column names, like this:

```
cols_to_fill = ['col_x', 'col_y', 'col_z', ...]

for col in cols_to_fill:
    df.loc[df[col].notnull(), col] = col]
```

Or, to do this over all columns in your dataframe:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[col].notnull(), col] = col]
```